# Could there be a ‘joke’ tag on SO Documentation?

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation

Would it be reasonable for SO Documentation to have a ‘joke’ tag for all of the different categories (topics) of programming joke?

It’s a shame that docs tags have to be Q&A question tags first, because a ‘joke’ tag would a nice outlet for the jokes that aren’t appropriate as traditional SO questions. Jokes aren’t answers to programming questions so they clearly don’t belong on the Q&A. I’m wondering whether means that they don’t belong in Documentation either, whether there’s a grey area about things that are worth documenting, or whether this just means waiting for Documentation to be added to http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

For the record, I’m asking this question seriously. Programming jokes have a useful cultural purpose (and just helping people get through the day sometimes) that is perhaps worth documenting.

Comment: They have a useful cultural purpose, but they don't have a place in Documentation nor on SO proper. There's a time and a place for everything.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That looks like a (good) answer to me, rather than a comment.

Comment: Funny that you mention programmers.se as the place where the jokes should go. I thought the NPR days are long forgotten by now...

Comment: If we wanted to have jokes on Stack Overflow, they would be more suited to a dedicated "Jokes" or "Humor" section *alongside* Documentation and Q&A. Not as an item within either of them. (Who in their right mind thinks of looking in the "documentation" when they're looking for jokes anyway?)

Comment: Oh, great idea, @BoltClock. That's exactly what we need. Another subsection. +15 reputation for every joke you contribute. :-(

Comment: The two hardest problems in computer science are trying to convince anyone on StackOverflow there's room for humour, and not getting your disparaging comments deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have a useful cultural purpose, but they don't have a place in Documentation nor on SO proper.

Programming jokes [used to be on topic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg0OyJ54vOAhWFtBoKHSzKAwAQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F76584%2Fwhat-happened-to-whats-your-best-programming-joke&usg=AFQjCNG2GBEIpARRSjqFIoZPH2lDFmZcJg&sig2=6dDvbtaQY7xANcFGl_egoA) on Stack Overflow in the olden days, but those times are long past: the focus has changed over time, moving more and more away from  anything that isn't actual, factual, hard programming questions.

The main motivation for this change is that allowing informal/unrelated content will invariably lead to things getting out of control. It is much easier to post and consume "fun" content than boring, factual Q&A. The only way to prevent the fun stuff from taking over is to ban it altogether.

That's the current status on the SO/SE network - if you want to socialize and have fun, check out chat and (to some, very limited extent) the Meta sites. Everywhere else, fun is off topic for good reasons.

Comment: FWIW For me it’s more about collecting classic jokes than having fun. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with collecting those - but the community has really resoundingly rejected the suggestion that they should be collected *here*. (There's loads of discussion, for and against, here on Meta, if you want to inflict it on yourself to read it. :)